# Why is Stripe generating a card token even when the expiry year is absent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have the following method in `user.rb`:

```
  def create_card(params)
    begin
      token = Stripe::Token.create(:card => {
        :number => params["number"],
        :exp_month => params["expiry_month"],
        :exp_year => params["expiry_year"],
        :cvc => params["cvc"]})
    rescue Stripe::CardError => card
    end
    if token.present?
      begin
        card_object = Stripe::Customer.create(:card => token.id, :description => "#{token.card.type} #{token.card.last4}")
      rescue Stripe::CardError => card
      end
    end
    if card_object.present?
      card = self.cards.create! :card_id => card_object.id, :brand => token.card.type, :display_number => token.card.last4, :expiry_month => token.card.exp_month, :expiry_year => token.card.exp_year
    end
    return card
  end
```

It was generating tokens (and cards) even when I supplied it with incorrect card information, so I dropped into the method with Pry. Here's what I see:

```
> params
=> {"number"=>"4242424242424242", "cvc"=>"123", "expiry_month"=>"12", "expiry_year"=>""}
> token = Stripe::Token.create(:card => {
    :number => params["number"],
    :exp_month => params["expiry_month"],
    :exp_year => params["expiry_year"],
    :cvc => params["cvc"]})
=> #<Stripe::Token:0x3ffec3d0e9d4 id=test_tok_1> JSON: {
  "id": "test_tok_1",
  "livemode": false,
  "used": false,
  "object": "token",
  "type": "card",
  "card": {"id":"test_cc_2","object":"card","last4":"4242","type":"Visa","brand":"Visa","funding":"credit","exp_month":"12","exp_year":"","fingerprint":"eXWMGVNbMZcworZC","customer":"test_cus_default","country":"US","name":"Johnny App","address_line1":null,"address_line2":null,"address_city":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_country":null,"cvc_check":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_zip_check":null,"number":"4242424242424242","cvc":"123"}
}
```

Why is it generating a token?

When I inspect the card object that this method returns, I get:

```
> card
+----+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------+
| id | card_id    | display_number | expiry_month | expiry_year | brand | created_at              | updated_at              | order_id | user_id |
+----+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------+
| 2  | test_cus_3 | 4242           | 12           |             | Visa  | 2016-03-03 23:46:41 UTC | 2016-03-03 23:46:41 UTC |          | 1       |
+----+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+---------+
> card.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ff13f1cb7d0
 @base=
  #<Card:0x007ff13f1e9d70
   id: 2,
   card_id: "test_cus_3",
   display_number: "4242",
   expiry_month: 12,
   expiry_year: nil,
   brand: "Visa",
   created_at: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 23:46:41 UTC +00:00,
   updated_at: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 23:46:41 UTC +00:00,
   order_id: nil,
   user_id: 1>,
 @messages={}>
```

Comment: Did you the token id like tok_ with test_tok_1 ? I just tested this out by directly calling the API with curl and was not able to reproduce this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely shouldn't work:

```
[1] pry(main)> require "stripe"
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_..."
=> "sk_test_..."
[3] pry(main)> params = {"number"=>"4242424242424242", "cvc"=>"123", "expiry_month"=>"12", "expiry_year"=>""}
=> {"number"=>"4242424242424242",
 "cvc"=>"123",
 "expiry_month"=>"12",
 "expiry_year"=>""}
[4] pry(main)> token = Stripe::Token.create(:card => {
[4] pry(main)*     :number => params["number"],
[4] pry(main)*     :exp_month => params["expiry_month"],
[4] pry(main)*     :exp_year => params["expiry_year"],
[4] pry(main)* :cvc => params["cvc"]})
Stripe::CardError: Your card's expiration year is invalid.
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/stripe-1.36.0/lib/stripe.rb:310:in `handle_api_error'
```

I would recommend checking the [logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?method=not_get) in your dashboard to find out the actual content of the token creation request.

Comment: Thx -- it was an issue with StripeMock

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're providing a succeeding card number param.  All of the test numbers are [documented here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing).

This particular number will always succeed, regardless of whether you specify a valid expiry year.

If you're attempting to raise an `expired_card` `CardError`, try using `4000000000000069`

Comment: That is not correct, an expiration year is required to generate a card token. Passing a string would return an invalid_request_error